# error in getting categorial features from train dataset

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, data-visualization, feature-extraction

My train data looks something like this:
[train data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vtr1.png)

To extract categorial features out of it I ran following code"

```
categorial=[c for c in train.columns if train.columns(c).dtype in ['object'] ]
```

But I am getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-31eb7ac47e21> in <module>
----> 1 categorial=[c for c in train.columns if train.columns[c].dtype in ['object'] ]

<ipython-input-31-31eb7ac47e21> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 categorial=[c for c in train.columns if train.columns[c].dtype in ['object'] ]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   4295         if is_scalar(key):
   4296             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key, warn_float=True)
-> 4297             return getitem(key)
   4298 
   4299         if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

What is the possible solution?

Comment: with that also it is giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to select the 'object' type variables-

```
categorical = train.select_dtypes('object')
```

If you just want the variable names -

```
categorical_cols = train.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks!! But what was wrong in my code? Can u correct it please!!

Comment: That is simply not the right way to get the columns based on type. If your question is answered, can you upvote and accept the answer.